# Value not be empty workaround in cypress

Tags: cypress

Please cypress is giving me undefined error when I want to check that the input is not empty like this:

```
cy.get('car').find('input').should('not.be.empty');
```

When I put a value into input like bmw and use a code like this, all is fine

```
cy.get('car').find('input').should('have.value', 'bmw');
```

So it finds the input and can read the value, but why the not.be.empty is not working? Is there some workaround to that? I do not want to specific the value of the field, could be random. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to check whether your `value` is empty or not. You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('car').find('input').invoke('val').should('not.be.empty')
```

Comment: Omg, this was soo easy. Thx :}

Answer (score 2):

An empty input will have a string value of "".

```js
cy.get('car').find('input').should('not.have.value', '');
```

The assertion `.should('not.be.empty')` applies to the text content  e.g `<div>MyText</div>`.

Comment: This will fail, because the value should not be empty. I do not want to check if its empty :}

Comment: Pretty easy to assert the negative, just add `not`